# Reactjs function for changing state elements based on two inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have a front-end in react-mui with a list of 8 words and each word has its state updated based on its input and it may also be disabled. Example:

```
        <TextField required id="standard-basic" disabled={this.state.word1Disabled} label="Word1" value={this.state.word1} onChange={(event) => this.setState({word1:event.target.value.trim()})} />
        <TextField required id="standard-basic" disabled={this.state.word2Disabled} label="Word2" value={this.state.word2} onChange={(event) => this.setState({word2:event.target.value.trim()})} />
```

The user can decide which of the 8 words to disable using a dropdown menu which implements the following function:

```
    const handleWord = event => {

    switch(event.target.value) {
        case "1":
          this.setState({word1Disabled:true,word2Disabled:false,word3Disabled:false,word4Disabled:false,word5Disabled:false,word6Disabled:false,word7Disabled:false,
            word8Disabled:false})
          break;
        case "2":
            this.setState({word1Disabled:false,word2Disabled:true,word3Disabled:false,word4Disabled:false,word5Disabled:false,word6Disabled:false,word7Disabled:false,
                word8Disabled:false})
          break;
        case "3":
            this.setState({word1Disabled:false,word2Disabled:false,word3Disabled:true,word4Disabled:false,word5Disabled:false,word6Disabled:false,word7Disabled:false,
                word8Disabled:false})
          break;
        case "4":
            this.setState({word1Disabled:false,word2Disabled:false,word3Disabled:false,word4Disabled:true,word5Disabled:false,word6Disabled:false,word7Disabled:false,
                word8Disabled:false})
          break;
        case "5":
            this.setState({word1Disabled:false,word2Disabled:false,word3Disabled:false,word4Disabled:false,word5Disabled:true,word6Disabled:false,word7Disabled:false,
                word8Disabled:false})
          break;
        case "6":
            this.setState({word1Disabled:false,word2Disabled:false,word3Disabled:false,word4Disabled:false,word5Disabled:false,word6Disabled:true,word7Disabled:false,
                word8Disabled:false})
          break;
        case "7":
            this.setState({word1Disabled:false,word2Disabled:false,word3Disabled:false,word4Disabled:false,word5Disabled:false,word6Disabled:false,word7Disabled:true,
                word8Disabled:false})
          break;
        case "8":
            this.setState({word1Disabled:false,word2Disabled:false,word3Disabled:false,word4Disabled:false,word5Disabled:false,word6Disabled:false,word7Disabled:false,
                word8Disabled:true})
          break;

      }

     }
```

While the above solution solves my problem, I assume it's not good programming practice because it's over repetitive. Could someone confirm if I am on the right track?

Now I want to give the user the ability to disable two words at the same time using the dropdown menu, say word 1 and 2. How can I modify the handleWord function to achieve such? I tried to think about it but the way I think it is becoming even more repetitive, handling EVERY possible case for each of the two words disabled (8x8 = 64 cases lol).

The desired outcome is that the user will be able to pick two words they want to disable and those textfields receive the "disabled={true}" property. If the user changes their mind and want to change the word, then the old disabled textfield becomes enabled again.

Comment: To get round the repetitiveness, you need to think about it slightly differently e.g. you can combine the entire logic into on line by doing something like `this.setState({word1Disabled: event.target.value === "1", word2Disabled: event.target.value === "2"...etc...etc`). Personally, I would not use conditional logic the that to act on the value because like you have noticed, you will have to keep adding a tiny bit more code ->

Comment: I would just push the value into array and set that into state and then you check if it is disabled by doing something something `disabledWords.includes(myValue)` so then the handler wouldn't need to be modified if more words are added

Comment: @Tom Finney   good idea about combining the entire logic. I am still trying to understand what exactly you mean in the second comment. Do you mean pushing all word values in an array and then remove them when "disabled"?

Comment: @Drew Reese I am looking now for both words to be disabled at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, exactly something like that. If you think about using an array to store references to what is disabled, you can essentially remove all that code you wrote. I threw together this quick code sandbox to demonstrate it: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hofstadter-cg67i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following line of code for your 8x8 = 64 cases :)

```
this.setState({['word' + event.target.value + 'Disabled']: true});
```

**For Disabling by multiple input:**

```
"1,3,5".split(',').map(value => {
            this.setState({['word' + value + 'Disabled']: true});
        });
```

**Here is the complete Example:**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
export class WordsDisable extends Component {
    state = {
            word1Disabled: false,
            word2Disabled: false,
            word3Disabled: false,
            word4Disabled: false,
            word5Disabled: false,
            word6Disabled: false,
            word7Disabled: false,
            word8Disabled: false
        };

    handleWord= (event) => {
        // Setting false for all words
        this.setState({
            word1Disabled: false,
            word2Disabled: false,
            word3Disabled: false,
            word4Disabled: false,
            word5Disabled: false,
            word6Disabled: false,
            word7Disabled: false,
            word8Disabled: false
        });

        this.setState({['word' + event.target.value + 'Disabled']: true});
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <input onChange={this.handleWord}/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Last but not the least, You dont need to update all property using setState. You just update your single property and rest will keep the previous value. For example:

```
switch (event.target.value) {
    case "1":
        this.setState({word1Disabled: true});
        break;
    case "2":
        this.setState({word2Disabled: true});
        break;
    case "3":
        this.setState({word3Disabled: true});
        break;
    case "4":
        this.setState({word4Disabled: true});
        break;
}
```

Comment: Almost. Trying to apply it to the case where you have two inputs that disable two words at the same time. Yours works very well for one input however.

Comment: Hi, @Sophie259, I have added one more example in my answer. I tested it. It works for multiple input. can you please check that?

Comment: Fantastic :) I was using Tom's code sanbox and was iterating over an array but the mapping part is good idea as well.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation :)